# How to call a object method on an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using math.js and I want to call the method `addFive` on every element of the array `x`. If I call `addFive` on a variable like `y`, it works fine. I get an output of 10.

```
x = math.matrix([2,3,4]);
let y= 5;
function example(){
    this.a=5;
    this.addFive = function(x){
        return (x+this.a);
    }
}
ex = new example();
let w = ex.addFive(y);
console.log(w);
```

when I tried this,

```
let w = math.map(x, addFive);
console.log(w);
```

I am getting an error that `addFive is not defined`. is there a way around this without using loops?

Comment: addFive isn't publically available, it's a method on your example class

Comment: `math`/`math.matrix` is missing as well.

Comment: To answer this, we need to know what `math.matrix` and `math.map` are.

Comment: I am using math.js lib. math.matrix creates a matrix, pretty much like an array. math.map works exactly like .map, it takes two args, creates a new matrix or array with the results of the callback function executed on each entry of the matrix/array.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the function as `ex.addFive` since `addFive` is only defined in your `ex` object.

Also, you must bind the function to `ex` to pass the right context for `this.a` to work inside the method.

Note that you can also use `matrix.map(fn)` instead of `math.map(matrix, fn)`. Combined with an arrow function defined inline, this simplifies to:

```
console.log(math.matrix([2, 3, 4]).map(x => x + 5));
```

Here is an example:

```js
function example() {
    this.a = 5;
    this.addFive = function (x) {
        return x + this.a;
    }
}
const ex = new example();

console.log(ex.addFive(5));
console.log(math.matrix([2, 3, 4]).map(ex.addFive.bind(ex)).toString());
console.log(math.map(math.matrix([2, 3, 4]), ex.addFive.bind(ex)).toString());
console.log(math.matrix([2, 3, 4]).map(x => x + 5).toString());
```

```html
<script language="JavaScript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/5.8.0/math.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Mark Meyer, without bind, the values are NaN in the resulting matrix

Comment: Oh yes, I was looking at it from a different angle. If you pass the raw function reference you do need it.

Comment: what a pitty, that `mathjs` does not support `thisArg` for mapping.

Answer (score 2):

Since `addFive` is a method on an instance, you need to call it through the instance. You can do this by calling `ex.addFive()` instead of the bare `addFIve()` which isn't defined as a standalone function.

```js
x = math.matrix([2,3,4]);

function example(){
    this.a=5;
    this.addFive = function(x){
        return (x+this.a);
    }
}

ex = new example();

let w = math.map(x, (n) => ex.addFive(n));
console.log(w);
```

```html
<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.3.0/math.min.js></script>
```

Of course, if you are just making this object to use an `addFive()` method, you are probably better off just defining it as a function, which will make everything simpler:

```js
x = math.matrix([2,3,4]);

const addFive = (x) => x + 5

let w = math.map(x, addFive);
console.log(w);
```

```html
<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.3.0/math.min.js></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `math.map` will take an array (or matrix) as the first parameter and a function to run against each as the second, then you need to pass a *function*. Right now `addFive` is a method defined on the instance of `example` objects. So, you first need to create one object to be able to access that code

```
let ex = new example();
```

Next you need to pass a code that calls `ex.addFive`

```
let w = math.map(x, item => ex.addFive(item));
```

```js
x = math.matrix([2,3,4]);

function example(){
    this.a=5;
    this.addFive = function(x){
        return (x+this.a);
    }
}

ex = new example();

let w = math.map(x, item => ex.addFive(item));
console.log(w);
```

```html
<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.3.0/math.min.js></script>
```

this way you run `ex.addFive` against each item in this matrix

Do note that you can also pass the reference to `addFive` directly but you'll run into an error

```
math.map(x, ex.addFive)
```

```js
x = math.matrix([2,3,4]);

function example(){
    this.a=5;
    this.addFive = function(x){
        return (x+this.a);
    }
}

ex = new example();

let w = math.map(x, ex.addFive);
console.log(w);
```

```html
<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.3.0/math.min.js></script>
```

This is because the `this` context would be lost when `.map` executes the callback and `addFive` uses `this.a`. You can preserve the context [by using `.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

```
math.map(x, ex.addFive.bind(ex))
```

```js
x = math.matrix([2,3,4]);

function example(){
    this.a=5;
    this.addFive = function(x){
        return (x+this.a);
    }
}

ex = new example();

let w = math.map(x, ex.addFive.bind(ex));
console.log(w);
```

```html
<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.3.0/math.min.js></script>
```

This is an alternative to passing a callback like the previous one `item => ex.addFive(item)` - the two are equivalent and it matters little which one you pick. I personally dislike using `.bind` in this case because you already have **ex**.bind only to follow it with .bind(**ex**). It looks a bit ridiculous.

Another alternative is to change the functionality - you only need to establish the context of the function, if uses `this` if you change `example` to

```
function example(){
    this.addFive = function(x){
        return (x+5);
    }
}
```

then there is no usage of `this` which means that you can call `math.map(x, ex.addFive)` and get the correct result.

```js
x = math.matrix([2,3,4]);

function example(){
    this.addFive = function(x){
        return (x+5);
    }
}

ex = new example();

let w = math.map(x, ex.addFive);
console.log(w);
```

```html
<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.3.0/math.min.js></script>
```

Answer (score -3):

addFive is a function that requires one input in it. try to use

```
let w = math.map(x, addFive(5));
console.log(w);
```

Comment: Please take a close look at the code OP posted. The error clearly states `addFive` is not defined. If it was a parameter issue no error or a different error would be thrown.

Comment: `addFive` is a *method* thus it needs to be called from the context of an object.